# Adding instance methods during class definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, metaprogramming

I'm currently working on my first gem and making my first experiences in meta programming.

Therefore, I would like some feedback on how to correctly define an instance method during a class definition.

Specifically, I created this module that you are supposed to `extend` in your ActiveRecord models like this:

```
class Duck < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend UnitedAttributes::Model
  attr_accessible :name, :weight
  unite :weight, :kilogram
end
```

Here is the source for the `UnitedAttribues::Model` module. https://github.com/nielsbuus/united_attributes/blob/master/lib/united_attributes/model.rb

And here is a shortened version without *superfluous* code:

```
module UnitedAttributes
  module Model

    def unite(accessor, unit, options = {})    
      class_eval do
        define_method "united_#{accessor}" do
          Attribute.new(self.send(accessor), options)
        end
      end
    end

  end
end
```

It appears to work, but I have some concerns:

1. Is `class_eval` the correct method to use here?
2. Is `define_method` the correct method to use here?
3. An options hash is passed into the class method, and used inside the instance method body. Is this safe? Any memory concerns?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html), that would be a standardized way of doing this.

If not, you could always do something similar.

I wouldn't be worried about memory concerns. A hash is small, generally speaking. What I would be worried about is if the caller that passes in these options is unaware you'll be persisting them. For example:

```
options = { :foo => 'var', :bar => 'example' }

unite :name_1, :unit_a, options

options.delete(:example)

unite :name_2, :unit_b, options
```

In this case, the modification of the `options` hash would impact both inadvertently. One way around this is to `dup` or `clone` the incoming options, or better, to pick out the values you want and raise an exception if an unknown argument is received. The `options` hash should not be considered the property of the `unite` method.

You'll also run in to trouble if a caller passes in a `frozen` set of options. Your call to `merge!` will produce an exception. In general, manipulating an argument passed in to a method is considered bad form unless the method is specifically intended to perform that kind of function.

Comment: The caller should create an options hash explicitly for this method during class definition, so it should be okay to mutate it. The exception suggestion is interesting though, because I do want to secure the gem so the caller will know he's doing it wrong as quickly as possible.

Comment: I will look into ActiveSupport::Concern tomorrow, thank you for the suggestion.